# MySite Feature stapling

Tags: my-site, feature-stapling

I need to add a custom webpart to default.aspx page of created MySite. I followed [this](http://www.greggalipeau.com/2011/07/12/sharepoint-provision-default-webparts-for-mysites/) post and it is working well. What is strange thou, it works well for users that authenticate via Windows Autehntication. When I'm creating MySite for user authenticated via ADFS, code runs smooth until, but `Provisioned` flag never changes its status - it's always false, so while loop `RunProcess` never exits. Do you have any clue why this might be happening? Could it be because of lack of profile synchronization (I have UPS, but not all profiles are up-to-date)?

Comment: Reading through that article I notice the Thread.Sleep... This doesn't feel like a very sensible approach as it will not scale beyond a smallish number of users and will impact the farm performance if many threads are slept at a time.

Comment: I didn't find any other soluction. When I try to add web part in feature receiver without additional thread, I'm getting error that `default.aspx` is not available. It is available when site is provisioned, but `Provisioned` flag for site's root web never changes to true when user is logged differently than by AD.

Comment: I have the same problem, provisioned never turns true, any help?